# Error while building 'luac' executable in RHEL6.6

Tags: lua

I am trying to build lua-5.3.1 in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6 platform. Following binaries will be build :

1. shared library : liblua.so
2. executable     : lua
3. executable     : luac

I have made the following changes in the provided Makefile :

---

Existing :

```
CC= gcc -std=gnu99 
LUA_A=  liblua.a 
$(LUA_A): $(BASE_O)
          $(AR) $@ $(BASE_O)
          $(RANLIB) $@
```

Modified :

```
CC= gcc -fPIC
LUA_A=  liblua.so
$(LUA_A): $(BASE_O)
          $(CC) -mthreads -shared -o $(LUA_A) $(BASE_O)
```

---

'liblua.so' and 'lua' have been built successfully using the modified Makefile. But during 'luac' build following linking error is coming :

```
 gcc -fPIC -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_2 -DLUA_USE_LINUX    -c -o luac.o luac.c
 gcc -fPIC -o luac   luac.o liblua.so -lm -Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline
 luac.o: In function `PrintFunction':
 luac.c:(.text+0x947): undefined reference to `luaP_opnames'
 luac.c:(.text+0x963): undefined reference to `luaP_opmodes'
 luac.o: In function `pmain':
 luac.c:(.text+0x11db): undefined reference to `luaU_dump'
 /usr/bin/ld: luac: hidden symbol `luaU_dump' isn't defined
 /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[1]: *** [luac] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/disk1/u10rhel66/lua-5.3.1/src' 
 make: *** [linux] Error 2
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try setting `LUAI_FUNC` to plain `extern` in `luaconf.h` (but that will export many private symbols from the shared library), or link `luac` with a static `liblua.a` as @lhf suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`luac` must be built statically linked with `liblua.a`.

If you really want `luac` linked dynamically, try this:

- remove `LUAI_DDEF` and `LUAI_DDEC` from `lopcodes.c` and `lopcodes.h`
- remove `LUAI_FUNC` from `lundump.h`
- rebuild